# Can I tie in an external serial key generator to InstallShield LE for VS2012?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, installshield, key-generator

I created an installer for my Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project and succeeded. Now, I want to add in a product key generator or serial key generator that so the user can only install the project if they provide a valid serial key.

Is it possible to combine an external serial key generator with InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012? If so, how and how do I make sure that the user enters the appropriate key and that that key is validated before proceeding with the install?

I had a hard time finding information on this topic, so I thought just to ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in short, no because :

1. InstallShield LE doesn't have the feature; you need to buy a licensed InstallShield product that has that feature. This feature is not cheap; and
2. VS2012 doesn't have the feature because it doesn't care how you manage your product sales.

If you don't want to purchase a third party product, you need to implement your own library that will ship with your software that does license checking with a server which you must also implement.

I would recommend Lindersoft SetupBuilder 8 if you go with a 3rd party product.  It is cheap and easy to use.

Comment: Another affordable and powerful option is the Professional edition from Advanced Installer, http://www.advancedinstaller.com/search.html?cx=006686361644407349086%3Ayneweleowua&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=serial+validation

Comment: If a purchase third party serial key generators, would they package will with InstallShield? Would I need the full licensed version of InstallShield or can I just use InstallShield LE?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. It dpnds on how the key gens work.  If you're validating serial numbers at run-time, then you would update your code with 3rd party tool code and you can install all assemblies using InstallShield.  If instead you're trying to validate serial numbers during install process you will need to do a lot of customizing the installer process.  Don't think your only option is to use InstallShield LE. It would be much easier 2 use 1 package and go with it. Meaning buy InstallShield features or buy a product mentioned in my answer/comments. Mix&matching will get ugly.

Comment: I think my company might have access to full InstallShield license, so I was wondering if I just customize the dialogs to match a third party key generator, would that be possible using InstallShield? Also, is there an InstallShield product that contains serial key generation for the sake of simplicity? Thanks!